# Call external javascript file from a select drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have a select drop down:

```
<select lang="en" >
<option label=" Select a keyboard language" selected="selected" />
<option value="af" label="Afrikaans / Afrikaans" />
<option value="sq" label="Albanian / shqipe" />
<option value="ar" label="Arabic / العربية" />
<option value="hy" label="Armenian / Հայերեն" />
    ........
</select>
```

I have external JavaScript files (C:[PATH]\js_files):
af.js, sq.js, ar.js, hy.js, etc.

**How do I call *and* load the relative external JavaScript files when a user makes a language selection?**

My js skills are not so great as to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: `document.appendChild(document.createElement("script"))` and so on

Comment: I don't know... maybe send an ajax call to a php page, create a $_SESSION['lan'] = 'en', and than refresh the page using the session to load the js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially you are only looking for this? :

javascript in head:

```
function loadJS(v){
    var d=document, h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], newScript;
    try {h.removeChild(d.getElementById('lib_lang'));} catch (e){}
    newScript      = d.createElement('script');
    newScript.id   = 'lib_lang';
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src  = '[PATH]/'+v+'.js';   // change your path here
    h.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

html in body:

```
<select lang="en" onchange="loadJS(this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true"> Select a keyboard language</option>
    <option value="af">Afrikaans / Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="sq">Albanian / shqipe</option>
    <option value="ar">Arabic / العربية</option>
    <option value="hy">Armenian / Հայերեն</option>
</select>
```

[DEMO JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3R6uj/).

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you. That is a great help.